How to be sure this cross product is well defined
I am viewing an introduction course to set theory at uni. we have only developed the first six axioms (extensionality, empty set, binary set, separation, union set, and power set). During this part of the course we have been working with the book Set theory, a first course by Cunningham.
We have defined the cross product $A \times B = \{(a,b): a \in A \land b \in B\}$. At the moment, I am resolving the exercise 3.1.4, basically the task is to prove that given the sets A and C then $$\cup A\times C = \cup \{B\times C : B \in A\}$$
Before jumping on to solving this issue, the teacher asked us to first confirm if given any arbitrary sets A, C the set $S=\{B\times C : B \in A\}$ is well defined.
My answer to this question was that any such set is only well defined as long as $A \neq \emptyset$ and here's my reasoning:
Suppose that $A = \emptyset$ and S exists, then by definition of $S$ there is an element $s \in S$ such that $s = (x,y)$ for a given $x \in B$ and a given $y \in C$. But by definition of $S, x \in A$. Which is a contradiction to the axiom of existence (the empty set). Thus $S$ is not well defined for every A and C.
Now, when considering $\cup A\times C = \cup \{B\times C : B \in A\}$, I'm not really sure how to proceed, because I feel like I am getting two cases, if $A = \emptyset$ and if $A \neq \emptyset$.
The first case does not worry me too much because I just need to prove $\cup A \times C \subseteq \cup S$ and $\cup S \subseteq \cup A \times C$, which I am currently working on (will edit once I'm done).
But if $A = \emptyset$, it would follow that $S$ does not exist, so I am quite a bit confused on that.

"by definition of $S$ there is an element $s \in S$" ... No. There's your error.

Nvm, I have rethought the problem in a different light. Asking if S is well defined in this case is asking where S lives, namely what set does S belong to.
A while ago we had proven that given any two sets $A$ and $B$, then $$(\forall a \in A)(\forall b \in B) (a,b) \in \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A \cup C))$$
With this in mind, and having $ \psi (B)$ be the property $B \in A$, by the axiom of separation we can construct the set $S = \{B \times C \in \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A \cup C): \psi (B) = B \in A \}$ thus S is well defined.
For the sake of discussion, here's how I've proved the above statement:
Given the sets $A$ and $B$, and $a \in A$ fixed but arbitrary and $b \in B$ fixed but arbitrary, it follows that  $a,b \in A \cup B$.
By the pairing axiom, the sets $\{a\}$ and $\{a, b\}$ exist. Now, these are subsets of $A \cup B$, thus $\{a\}, \{a, b\} \in \mathcal{P}(A \cup C)$.
And applying the axiom of pairs, we have the set $\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$, which by definition is the ordered pair $(a,b)$. And as $(a,b) \subset \mathcal{P}(A \cup C)$ then it follows that $(a,b) \in \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A \cup C))$.
QED.
